# How to get char string from PyObject str?

Tags: python, c++, c

Hi i'm learning how to use python in c++ and am wondering how I convert the returned python value to something I can use in c++.

Here's my code:

```
    CPyInstance pyInstance;
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
    CPyObject pName = PyUnicode_FromString("Info");
    CPyObject pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    if (pModule)
    {
        CPyObject pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "getTracks");

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
        {
            CPyObject pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
            //print the returned string
        }
        else { std::cout << "Error: function getTracks()\n"; }
    }
    else { std::cout << "error: no module imported"; }

    return 0;
```

```
def getTracks():
    
    returnString = ""

    for track in results['tracks'][:10]:
        returnString += 'track    : ' + track['name']
      
    return returnString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functions from section [UTF-8 Codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#utf-8-codecs).

For example, [PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize):

```cpp
CPyObject pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
Py_ssize_t size;
const char* data = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(pValue.getObject(), &size);
std::cout << std::string(data, size) << std::endl;
```

Or [PyUnicode_AsUTF8](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8)

```cpp
const char* data = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(pValue.getObject());
std::cout << data << std::endl;
```

> **`const char* PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(PyObject *unicode, Py_ssize_t *size)`**
>
> Return a pointer to the `UTF-8` encoding of the Unicode `object`, and store the size of the encoded representation (in bytes) in `size`. The `size` argument can be `NULL`; in this case no size will be stored. The returned buffer **always has an extra null byte appended (not included in size)**, regardless of whether there are any other null code points.
>
> This caches the UTF-8 representation of the string in the Unicode `object`, and subsequent calls will return a pointer to the same buffer. The caller is not responsible for deallocating the buffer.
>
> [...]
>
> **`const char* PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject *unicode)`**
>
> As `PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize()`, but does not store the size.